# child POM jar classes not showing up in another child project

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, wsdl2java

I have two child POMs. one to generate jar from wsdl and another one to use that jar to do some web service call stuff.
As the first step, jar got generated from wsdl successfully as expected and I see classes in jar using jar explorer.
next when i add this jar as dependency in the second child POM, it gets added in the maven dependency folder. but I'm unable to refer those classes from added jar in the second child project.
What would be reason for this? Am I missing something here? Please advice. 
Note: I'm using Eclipse IDE
Thanks,
Jey

Comment: Maybe you should show your pom.xml relevant parts? It's hard to guess. Does child pom really have a dependency for that other child project in dependencies? It shouldn't be available just because they share same parent project.

Comment: Link to JarExplorer: https://github.com/javalite/jar-explorer